# Facebook Messenger set Receiver Roles via API

Tags: facebook, messenger

I know how to subscribe to a Facebook page for my bot, but I have no idea how to set the particular applications into Primary Receiver and Secondary Receiver modes programmatically in order to setup handover protocol.

This can be done manually, of course, but I'd rather not have to have a user go into the page's settings to do so.  Is there an API call to set these roles?

The Facebook Page settings uses this URL to set this, but I can't find an API equivalent:

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/settings/messaging/subscribed_apps/?action=set_app_role&app_id=<app_id>&page_id=<psid>&app_roles[0]=primary_receiver
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/handover-protocol

Comment: I have the same question. Handover Protocol in the comment link above is specific to each user who messages the Page, but not the Page setting for all users. Any update on this?

Comment: I'm sorry, Jay.  I still have no answer to this issue.  It is definitely painful for my company since we have lots of customers that we service and making them go into their page configuration and set this up has been frustrating, to say the least.